# How to divide the observations of a variable in R dataframe?

Tags: r, split

**Hi people**.

Let's say that I have a dataframe with "x" number of variables and "y" number of observations. What I want to do is *divide* "y.1" into parts, for example,the observation has 16 digits: *2600100010055001*  the first two digits indicate the state, the next four digits indicate the municipality and so on. The entire data set is huge and other enviroments such as LibreOffice (I'm trying to educate myself in an open source enviroment) is not very efficient. I guess this is simple for a more mature Ruser, but for now this apparently simple task is hard for me to understand. Any hints are welcomed. Sudo!

Comment: You can use `read.fwf` and specify the `widths`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint.